# Is there a way to get required parameter from context AND user's speech?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent which has a required parameter called 'name'. If the user says, "My name is John" then name=John.

Now, I've defined an input context which stores name=John and is part of the same intent. The next time the user says something mapped to this intent as a follow-up, I don't want the agent to ask for the name again because its already stored in the context.

However, the agent does ask for the name again. How can I make it so that it gets the value from the context if its available?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably define another intent which takes the same input, except this intent should already have the name as input context while the other one will have a blank input context. From the following URL:

https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-contexts

> Input contexts limit intents to be matched only when certain contexts
>   are set.
>
> For example we can create two intents for requests like “I want to
>   hear more of them”.

There is also an example on that page.